# Angular how to send both header and body using HttpClient

Tags: angular, express

I am trying to send user information and jwt token to my server but server is printing undefined when I try to access the request body.

Following is my Angular code:

```
  subscribeToPlan(jwtToken: string, stripeId: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    const authroizationToken = 'bearer '.concat(jwtToken);
    const httpBody = new HttpParams();
    const email = this.getEmailfromJwtToken(jwtToken);
    httpBody.set('email', email);
    httpBody.set('stripeId', stripeId);
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', authroizationToken);

    var result = this.http.post<any>(this.subscribeUrl, httpBody, {headers});
    return result;
  }

  getEmailfromJwtToken(jwtToken: string): string {
    var decode = jwtDecode(jwtToken);
    return decode.email;
  }
```

Following is my express controller code:

```
var subscription = require('../models/subscription');

exports.subscribe = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.stripeId); ---> undefined
    res.json(req.body);
}
```

I am new to Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
subscribeToPlan(jwtToken: string, stripeId: string): Observable<any> {
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
   const authroizationToken = 'bearer '.concat(jwtToken);
   const httpBody = new HttpParams();
   const email = this.getEmailfromJwtToken(jwtToken);

   headers = headers.append('Authorization', authroizationToken);

   let reqBodyObj = {"email":email, "stripeId": stripeId}

   var result = this.http.post<any>(this.subscribeUrl, reqBodyObj, {headers});
   return result;               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you straightforward answer to this question but for your future reference always try to explore any built in methods, check what they provide in their overload, if you are using VS code or any editor it will help you in that, for example in case of VS studio you can hover your mouse on method or press F12, it will provide you all the options that particular method provide. lets explore for example, if you hover on httpclient post method you will be able to see-

[image]

As you can see above http post 3rd parameter is options and its optional parameter(?) where you can include header in third parameter, in your case you have to send token so here we can send it:

```
 var reqheader=new HttpHeaders();
 reqheader= reqheader.append('Authorization', "Bearer Token");
 this.http.post(url,body,{headers:reqheader});
```

That's it, you can explore other options like if you are using Windows authenticated API where you have to send withCredentials. Also if you want to tell API a response type, by default it will be json but if you want to get in XML format you can provide it too.